# html_safe works locally but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am using html_safe which should allow embedded Instagram posts (and other styling) on our blog. This works completely fine locally, but doesn't work on production (heroku).

I have also tried "raw", and that doesn't seem to work either. I have the same problem with some unrelated code (not working on production, works locally).

Here is the line:

```
<%= @document_renderer.render(@blog.main).html_safe %>
```

Expected result is that Instagram embed (and other styling) should work, instead I just see raw html (you can see a full page with unprocessed html here: https://achefstour.com/blog/the-last-of-the-hong-kongs-dai-pai-dong)

So, I am not sure if this is a Heroku problem, or something else I am missing. How can I start to debug this?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You might start debugging in your `config/environment` files. If it's environment specific, you might have some configuration that's causing it. Hard to say more without knowing more about your app

Comment: Thank you very much. I apologise for the stupid question, but how would you go about debugging the env files? I have googled the config options that are different in development and production, but none seem applicable to this issue.

Comment: Probably this is because `@blog.main` is an escaped HTML fragment itself. You need to unescape it before rendering if you want `raw` to do the job. Try `raw(CGI.unescape_html(@blog.main))` etc. Sometimes CGI behaves strange (I remember mystic TypeError on ordinary strings), in this case, there are several gems that can help (htmlentities, nokogiri to name a few...)